# The domain of $f(x) = \ln (x + \sqrt{1+ x^2}).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The domain of $f(x) = \ln (x + \sqrt{1+ x^2}).$

My trial:

Because the domain of the natural logarithmic function must be strictly greater than 0, so I assumed this and arrived at: 
$$\sqrt{1+ x^2} > -x$$

But after this how can I complete? one side of the inequality I am sure that it is positive but the other side may be positive or negative, could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Have you tried graphing those two functions and seeing where the inequality holds?

Comment: Since $f(x)=\text{arcsinh}(x)$, the maximal domain of $f$ is the range of $\sinh$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, note that $\sqrt{1+x^2}>\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\ge-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note for $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$x+\sqrt{x^2+1} > x + \sqrt{x^2}=$

$x + |x| \ge 0.$

The domain is ?

Answer (score 0):

The range of square root function is all positive reals and 0. So the  inequality can be squared on both the sides which leads to 1>0 .

So the domain of the function is all the reals.

Comment: what about the $x$?

Comment: @Happy As is written:

$\sqrt{1+ x^2} > -x$      $|)^2$;

$1+ x^2 > x^2$         $|-x^2$;
;
$1>0 \implies x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

first it is logarathmic function. hence inside it 
only positive argument may enter
domain is R.
case 1: if x is positive or zero then no problem.
case2: if x is negative, then the term inside the root
             is got by squaring x and then adding 1.
             so obviously the square root will be greater 
             then x.
            hence all x negative in domain.